# Rails controller test undefined method variable_size_secure_compare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

After upgraded from Rails 5.1 to 5.2, getting following error from a controller that uses HTTP Basic Auth tests:

```
undefined method `variable_size_secure_compare' for 
ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils:Module
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails 5.2 removed this method, see [5.2 release note](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html#active-support-notable-changes).

Use `ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare` instead.